# Excel Array Formula, Multiple criteria

Tags: excel-formula, excel-2010

I have a table in which multiple weeks of data is stored and I'm trying to return a value based on 2 criteria.
Column A of the data sheet contains the date the report was ran (Always on the same day of the week - 24/05/17, 31/05/17 etc)

I've managed to return the value of column H by using an array formula, based on a cell value (Date) in ''Issues Data Quality Overview'!$B$4' using the following formula:

```
{=IFERROR(INDEX('Issues Log'!$H$1:$H$20000,SMALL(IF('Issues Data Quality Overview'!$B$4='Issues Log'!$A$1:$A$20000,ROW('Issues Log'!$A$1:$A$20000)-MIN(ROW('Issues Log'!$A$1:$A$20000))+1,""), ROW(A2))),"")}
```

That returns a value such as "IID-10225-22".

**Problem:** 
Now I need to look up that value in the same table, based on a date in another cell, and return column X. (essentially adding the returned value as a criteria).

In all honesty I'm lost as to how I'd do this.

Comment: It would be easier to visualize if you would give mock data and expected outputs.

Answer (score 0):

@Matthew. I understand your formula gives the list of values in column H with column A values matching 'Issues Data Quality Overview'!$B$4 in an ordered list.

Does your Issues Log, column H have multiple occurrence of the same value? (example: IID-10255-22 can have a value in Issues Log, column A that is not the same value as 'Issues Data Quality Overview'!$B$4).

If not, it doesn't make sense to use the result as a lookup value to get column X, you can simply change the code to:

```
{=IFERROR(INDEX('Issues Log'!$X$1:$X$20000,...}
```

If it does have multiple occurrences and you want to get the first occurrence of the result in column H and get the value in column X, best to add a formula right next to your array formula and do a VLOOKUP.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It does have multiple occurences (one per week) and I needed the one it picks each week to be a variable.

Answer (score 0):

I've scrapped the array formula, as it really slowed down the processing speed. Instead I've created a Unique ID (=IssueID&Date) and VLookup'd that.